# DB2 cookbook by Graeme Birchall?

Tags: db2, documentation

Not sure if this question is appropriate here but I believe that it is of some interest for the db2:ers of the site.

Once upon a time the DB2 Cookbook by Graeme Birchall could be downloaded from:

```
http://mysite.verizon.net/Graeme_Birchall
```

The account seems to be closed, does anyone know if these are hosted elsewhere by the author or by anyone else? I believe that the pdf's where a great contribution for the DB2 community so it is a pity to see them gone.

For 9.7 they can be downloaded from: db2hub.com/freebies Does the cookbook exist for later versions?

Comment: The DB2 cookbook was a superb resource, but I don't recall seeing any versions beyond 9.7. I do remember seeing a rant somewhere about the difficulties involved in producing the book in MS Word - perhaps it finally drove him to distraction! I had a go at converting it to LaTeX many years ago; got started well with an automated conversion of the first chapter of text (a horrid mishmash of vim macros and python!) but eventually gave up after failing to get any syntax rail-diagram generators working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote to the author, but I never received an answer. It seems the most recent version is for v9.7. The book can be obtained from db2hub or from the wayback machine. Anyway, I published all of them in my Google Drive:

- 7.2 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B86nuTd5nMTKZzQtaTVTLUZ5ckE/edit?usp=docslist_api
- 8.2 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B86nuTd5nMTKS3ItN25IX2djTGc/edit?usp=docslist_api
- 9.1 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B86nuTd5nMTKNFR1SU9PZkN6MnM/edit?usp=docslist_api
- 9.5 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B86nuTd5nMTKdzBkS01nUlZwYXc/edit?usp=docslist_api
- 9.7 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B86nuTd5nMTKd190MFptUEtoYXc/edit?usp=docslist_api

For things like this, we, the DB2 community, should work on collaborative project with collaborative tools. Let's suppose Graeme Birchall does not longer work with DB2, no-one will continue this precious work.

I advise to all of you to create open things, like open documents, open source tools in public forges, etc. My personal work around db2 is published in GitHub, and I am convinced of creating free stuff.

Comment: All these links are referenced in the db2-index of web resources that I have curated: https://github.com/angoca/db2-index/wiki

Answer (score 2):

As I found a lot of questions about the discontinuation of the book (and I myself tryied to contact Graeme Birchall and was not successfull) and I really found it very good, I decided to convert it to asciidoc and put it to the community in github. 
The first version is now online:
http://db2-sql-cookbook.org/